# Set italic text failed in new command definition

Tags: macros, italic

I'm defining new commands in my `.tex` file. Here's my code:

```
\newcommand{\subhead}[1]
  {
    {\itshape \flushright \subheadfont --#1 \par}
  }
```

I'm going to define a command that make some text(from parameter) as a standalone subhead of certain article in a book. However, the parameter text in this command turns out not italic. What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Thanks~

Some supplement:
It maybe helpful to write down entire document I wrote:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec} %Use Chinese fonts
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt
\setmainfont{Microsoft YaHei}
\newfontfamily\subheadfont{FZLiShu-S01S} %Define '\subheadfont'
\newcommand{\subhead}[1]{{\itshape \flushright \subheadfont --#1 \par}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Article}
\subhead{This is 副标题}
Some content in the article. 一些中文内容。
\end{document}
```

Comment: As an aside: It's not a good idea to use space characters in command definitions, they can introduce unwanted space, instead you should use the `%` to comment them out if you wish to break a line or indent. I can't show you in the comments, but you would want a `%` after your `{` on the second line and at the end of the third line too

Comment: What is `\subheadfont`? This is ... new to me, how have you defined it? Assuming there is a `\subheadfont` it is possible that it selects a font which does not have true italics

Comment: @Au101 Yeah, I should pay more attention on the space. I forgot to tell you that I'm using package `fontspec` and defined my own font used for subhead as `\subheadfont`.

Comment: @Trams Just compose a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and save the time explaining all the details.

Comment: al the heading code in your example is presumably not relevant, just make an example document that _defines the commands you use_ then does `\itshape \subheadfont abc` it will be italic or not depending on how you defined `\subheadfont`. perhaps it is enough to instead do `\subheadfont \itshape abc` it all depends on code you have not shown.

Comment: As far as I can see, the font FZLiShu-S01S is only available in upright shape. Does italic make sense for Chinese?

Comment: @egreg quick answer: no. But since MS Word produces fake italic, people think the TeX should be able to do it as well. So in package `xeCJK` there is `AutoFakeSlant` option.

Answer (score 2):

The package `xeCJK` provides `AutoFakeSlant` option. There is also `AutoFakeBold`. I do not have the font you called, so I will illustrate this by Arial Unicode MS.

Notice that latin letters are typeset in Latin Modern since `\setCJKmainfont` and `\newCJKfontfamily` affect only ideographs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xeCJK} %Use Chinese fonts
\setCJKmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\newCJKfontfamily\subheadfont[AutoFakeSlant]{Arial Unicode MS} %Define '\subheadfont'
\newcommand{\subhead}[1]{{\itshape \flushright \subheadfont --#1 \par}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Article}
\subhead{This is 副标题}
Some content in the article. 一些中文内容。
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

uhmm... I'm going to state some experiment result. It seems that the problem is not due to the new command definition. When I change the `\subheadfont` to be defined by some other fonts, for example, `Times New Roman` and write some English words as subhead(i.e. `\subhead{This is subhead}`) the English characters could be typeset italic. Moreover, when I adopt Chinese fonts, the Chinese characters could not be typeset italic. And `xelatex` gives some warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted
```

Therefore, I think is because that the font I adopted doesn't include the italic shaped characters.

Actually I don't know how fonts specifically works. That's only my speculation. Maybe someone expert at it may give a more correct answer :D

---

Some supplement:

I viewed a lot pages from the Internet and learned that there's actually no concept of bold or italic shape in Chinese characters. The reason why we want to apply bold or italic shape is due to the wide use of `Microsoft Word` application, where the bold and italic Chinese characters are just made fake. Also, it's possible to force the glyph to be italic or bold in LaTeX, it is not recommended. In order to emphasize some information in one article, you'd better use some dedicated fonts(e.g. some black fonts) to do that.

For more information, you can refer to [JustFont Blog](http://blog.justfont.com/).